# How can I wire a Mini-USB to Micro-USB cable?

Tags: usb, wiring, usb-device, computers, diagram

I'm trying to figure out how to connect the pins from a Micro-USB connector to a Mini-USB connector. I'm assuming it's more complex than just connecting the +5V to the +5v, GND to GND, D- to D- and D+ to D+. What else am I missing? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What requires you to connect a micro-USB to mini-USB directly?

Comment: You're missing ID to ID and shield to shield.

Comment: You are missing also the distinction of "A" and "B" variants of both connectors. They will define how the ID pin needs to be connected. And here comes the Daniel's question.

Comment: Why not use a USB-OTG microB-to-A(host) adapter, then fit a standard A(function)-to-miniB cable? This avoids the signal integrity problems of a homemade patch cable.

Comment: Crazy, I know, but I know these kinds of cables exist so I'm trying to figure out how to make 'em :) I apologize I was not clear...it would need to be a Mini-B (5 pin) to Micro-B (4 pin). Basically, with what I have on-hand, it'd be connecting one of [these](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Ay.aLVXXXXbGXFXXq6xXFXXX9/100-Pcs-Mini-USB-5-Pin-Male-Plug-Socket-Connector-With-Plastic-Cover-for-DIY.jpg) to one of [these](http://www.audiophonics.fr/16581-thickbox_default/micro-usb-male-plug-type-c-diy-gold-plated.jpg). I could also get a 5-pin Micro if that helped. Thank you my friends!

Comment: You still need to specify whether you're talking about a receptacle or a plug. Also, there's no such thing as a 4-pin Micro-B plug or receptacle. It has 5 pins. But typically, you just leave ID disconnected at the receptacle if you're not a USB host, and ID is not run as a wire in the cable so the cable only has 4 wires and shield.

Comment: I don't want to misuse terminology here...but the Micro-B plug will go to a host receptacle on a tablet device (Nvidia Shield), and the Mini-B plug will go to a peripheral keyboard. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem of interconnect, you need to define the function of your cable. The distinction between "A" and "B" variants (be it classic Type-A or B, or their mini/micro variants) is specifically to determine which one goes to host, and which goes to a device. The cables of this sort must be always of A-B type, not B-B.

The tablet device, if it is a strictly host, must have Type-A receptacle, micro or normal. To fit in, the cable end must be of squarish Type-uA, with ID pin grounded.

If the tablet has OTG functionality (which is likely), the ID pin ground makes the tablet to turn into HOST mode. If ID is floating, it will/should act as DEVICE.

Now, it become a common practice in tablets to use micro-B receptacles, and not micro A/B, even if the tablet's port has dual-role functionality.  To make such tablet to be a host, people have invented "[OTG adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D8YZ2SA)", which have u-B shape on one end, but has the ID pin grounded , and Type-A **receptacle** on the other end. Then you can use a standard Type-A to mini-B cable to connect to the old keyboard. Or you can try to solder a u-B connector and ground its ID pin, but it would require the overmold disassembly, and might be difficult. Alternatively you can get a cable with u-A end (square shape), and file off proper corners of its shroud, to make it fit into angled u-B receptacle. Then connect VBUS, GND, D+ and D- to your mini-B keyboard cable.

Since the keyboard is likely a Low-Speed device, no special care or workmanship is required to make this cable connection.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful. I have loose connectors, so I can experiment with this. If I solder the ID pin from a micro-B connector to ground...would I do the same on the mini-B side?

Comment: I'm dense. No, we don't want to ground the ID pin on the Mini (device) side, because then it turns to HOST mode---which is not what we want. Going to go give it a shot. Thanks again!